# Send email in Python like PHP

Tags: python, email, sendmail

I noticed that php just has one quick function to send emails and I'm wondering if I can do that in Python. I know that Python has an email module, but I understand that I need to be running an SMTP server to use that, whereas PHP can use sendmail.

I would preferably like to use Python 3 and any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Sending mail via sendmail from python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73781/sending-mail-via-sendmail-from-python)?

Comment: Why an upvote for a basic question that could be answered by a simple Google search or a search on SO?

Comment: @Sentinel - I didn't do it. Honest.

Comment: the answer below does not use os.popen, and therefore much better than answers in linked question from the comment above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is a [full tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm) for sending email in python..it looks like they do have sendmail function too..take a look at

```
try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
   print "Successfully sent email"
except SMTPException:
   print "Error: unable to send email"
```

Comment: I'll try that, putting the host in the constructor made me think that it needed a server running.

Comment: Could you please explain where is the example with unix "sendmail" in the tutorial? In php default option in .ini is using "/usr/sbin/sendmail" as the mail sending program. Are you referring to the same?