# Sending email not working on heroku

Tags: django, gmail

I have this function in forms.py. There is currently no email specifications in my settings.py.

```
def send_email(FROM_NAME,FROM,TO,SUB,MSG,EXISTING_EMAIL,EXISTING_PASSWORD):

    FROMADDR = "%s <%s>" % (FROM_NAME, FROM)
    LOGIN    = EXISTING_EMAIL
    PASSWORD = EXISTING_PASSWORD
    TOADDRS  = [TO]
    SUBJECT  = SUB

    msg = ("From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\r\n"  % (FROMADDR, ", ".join(TOADDRS), SUBJECT) )
    msg +=  MSG+"\r\n"

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.set_debuglevel(1)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(LOGIN, PASSWORD)
    server.sendmail(FROMADDR, TOADDRS, msg)
    server.quit()
```

I call it my `views.py` like so

```
send_email('my_name','from_me@gmail.com','to_som1@gmail.com','my      subject','mymessage','my_existing_email@gmail.com','password_to_existing_email')
```

This works locally. I have tested it with yahoomail and gmail. But when I upload to heroku  it gives the error "(535, '5.7.1 Please log in with your web browser and then try again. Learn more at\n5.7.1 support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 et6sm2577249qab.8')"

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your question is tagged "Django"; is there some reason you're not using Django's [built-in e-mail sending](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#quick-example) (which prevents header injection among other conveniences).

Comment: yeah I tried but was giving me errors!

Comment: Can you help me to get it working using django ?

Comment: Certainly. Show us the code you were using with `send_mail`, and the error message (copy and paste of traceback) you get when you try. Probably best to edit it into your existing question.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use this:

```
FROMADDR = "%s <%s>" % (your_name, your_email)
```

Comment: This code does not work when I upload to heroku. Do you know why? it gives the error "(535, '5.7.1 Please log in with your web browser and then try again. Learn more at\n5.7.1 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 et6sm2577249qab.8')"

Comment: It seems to be an issue with gmail authentification. Something to do with login/password, not about email headers. Double check your `LOGIN` and `PASSWORD` variables. Note that `LOGIN` is just your email address, not `Name <email>`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be building emails with string interpolation, that's a good way to get your site used to send spam via header injections.  See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74084/8427) for details on how to construct emails securely.

Generally speaking, when formatting from addresses, you should use the format `Display Name <email@example.com>`.  See [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) for details.

Comment: I uploaded to heroku and then when I try sending the mail I get the error "https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 z9sm2583649qae.15

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the page linked to in the error message?

> If you're repeatedly prompted for your username and password, or if
>   you're getting an 'invalid credentials' or 'web login required' error,
>   make sure your password is correct. Keep in mind that password are
>   case-sensitive.
>
> If you’re sure your password is correct, sign in to your account from
>   the web version of Gmail instead at http://mail.google.com
>
> In most cases signing in from the web should resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me. After getting the error `Please log in with your web browser and then try again. Learn more etc.` when trying to send email from my web application, I logged in to the email via browser from my local computer.

After I logged in, there was a yellow notification bar on top which asking me if I want to allow external application access my mail. I confirmed this and Google asked me to log in to the account from the application **within the next 10 mins**. This will white-list the application.