# Sending mail via sendmail command line from PHP

Tags: php, nginx, sendmail, rhel7

```
sendmail -s me@example.com
Subject:Salem
This is body of email
Ctrl+D
```

Shell script above **works fine** under RHEL-7 .

We need now to wrap this command line ( `sendmail` ) with php to get something like :

```
  <?php 
       sendmail('from@example.com',"this is title","blablalb","to@example.com") 
   ?>
```

How to ?
Is there PHP library should be installed under RHEL to be able to send email by PHP relaying on sendmail commmand line ?

---

Known that the same question has been posted HOWEVER , in the context of Python programming language , and this is [the best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73844/747579) until now :

```
def sendMail():
    sendmail_location = "/usr/sbin/sendmail" # sendmail location
    p = os.popen("%s -t" % sendmail_location, "w")
    p.write("From: %s\n" % "from@somewhere.com")
    p.write("To: %s\n" % "to@somewhereelse.com")
    p.write("Subject: thesubject\n")
    p.write("\n") # blank line separating headers from body
    p.write("body of the mail")
    status = p.close()
    if status != 0:
           print "Sendmail exit status", status
```

Comment: Php has a mail command that uses sendmail.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: It's not clear to me what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use system

```html
$command = '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -f sender@example.com < /email.txt';
system($command);
```