# Setting email content from string in email.message?

Tags: python, email

I'd like to send an email using Python.

There's sendmail ([Sending mail via sendmail from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73781/sending-mail-via-sendmail-from-python)), but also https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html.
It recommends constructing a message based on https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html and has a few examples https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html#email-examples which reads the message content from file:

```
# Open the plain text file whose name is in textfile for reading.
with open(textfile) as fp:
    # Create a text/plain message
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(fp.read())
```

I've tried

```
msg.set_content(b"test message sent locally")
```

but that results in `TypeError: set_bytes_content() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'maintype' and 'subtype'`. It seems https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.set_content requires a context manager?

How can a string be used to construct the message body?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is correct yet misleading. The default content manager (context manager is a different animal...) provides this `set_content` method (emphasize mine):

> ```
> email.contentmanager.set_content(msg, <'str'>, subtype="plain", charset='utf-8' cte=None, disposition=None, filename=None, cid=None, params=None, headers=None) 
> email.contentmanager.set_content(msg, <'bytes'>, maintype, subtype, cte="base64", disposition=None, filename=None, cid=None, params=None, headers=None) 
> email.contentmanager.set_content(msg, <'EmailMessage'>, cte=None, disposition=None, filename=None, cid=None, params=None, headers=None) 
> email.contentmanager.set_content(msg, <'list'>, subtype='mixed', disposition=None, filename=None, cid=None, params=None, headers=None)
> ```
>
> Add headers and payload to msg:
>
> Add a Content-Type header with a maintype/subtype value.
>
> For str, set the MIME maintype to text, and set the subtype to subtype if it is specified, or plain if it is not.
>
> For bytes, use the specified maintype and subtype, or **raise a TypeError if they are not specified**.
>
> ...

Long story make short, if you want to send a simple text message, pass a plain (unicode) string to `set_content`:

```
msg.set_content("test message sent locally")    # pass a str string and not a byte string
```